# Mirth Connect integration with REST api

Tags: rest, mirth

Is there a way to call REST api (or any other RPC) in Mirth connect.
Here is the scenario, I want to be able check validity of some filed, by calling a REST API with the value of a field in an incoming record, then decide how to route it, is this possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mirth destinations there are HTTP sender and Web service sender. you could use HTTP sender to call rest ful services